# Returning a generic task from a method

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to implement the following method, in the public IUserStore interface, as I am using custom authentication:

```
public Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
{
    var user = UserRetriever.GetUser(userId);
    return ???;
}
```

UserRetriever works fine, and gets me my User object, but how do I return it?

If I try this:

```
return await user;
```

I get told that my user object 'is not awaitable'. Is there an interface I can implement on User to make it awaitable?

Alternatively is there an awaitable container I can put user into, to return it from this method?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be async, why are you trying to behave as if it were?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FromResult`:

```
return Task.FromResult(user);
```

Note this only exists in .Net 4.5 and any user of your `FindByIdAsync` method will expect the fetch to occur asynchronously, which your current implementation does not do.

You may be able to create a task to do the retrieval instead:

```
return Task.Run(() => UserRetriever.GetUser(userId));
```

although this still has the problem of blocking.